# A self-consistent equation that turns into a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, differential-equations, generating-functions

Suppose the function $f(x,y)$ is defined on a small neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R} \times [0,\infty)$ and satisfies the self consistent equation
\begin{align*}
& f(x,y) = \frac{1}{1-y} + A_+(x,y) + A_-(x,y) \ , \tag{1}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
& A_{\pm}(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{2(1\pm\sqrt{y})^3} \, \frac{f\big(\frac{x}{1\pm\sqrt{y}},y\big) - f\big(\frac{x}{1\pm\sqrt{y}},0\big)}{y} \tag{2}
\end{align*}
and we are only interested in finding $f(x,0)$.

**Question:** Is $f$ or $f(x,0)$ uniquely defined? And how would one go about finding $f(x,0)$?

The problem with just letting $y$ go to zero is that we get
\begin{align*}
& f(x,0) = 1 + x^2 \partial_2 f(x,0) \ ,
\end{align*}
which does not give enough information to find $f(x,0)$. However solving (1) in its full form is extremely difficult, since the $f$s is (2) have changed inputs.

I am hoping that there is some argument that takes the solution of (1) on a small strip $(-1,1) \times [0,\varepsilon]$ and that the simple form of (1), when $y \searrow 0$ allows for an easier way of finding $f(x,0)$.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If $f$ is smooth enough (so that $\partial_2 f(x,0)=o(1/x^2)$), then $f(x,0) = 1 + x^2 \partial_2 f(x,0)$ implies $f(x,0) =1$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Sorry, I'm having difficulty seeing this. Doesn't the smoothness condition only imply $f(0,0) = 1$, which we already know, since $f(0,y) = \frac{1}{1-y}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For convenience, let us write
$$ B_\pm(m,n,h;x,y) = \frac{x^m}{(1\pm \sqrt{y})^{n}} \frac{h(\frac{x}{1\pm \sqrt{y}},y) - h(\frac{x}{1\pm\sqrt{y}},0)}{y} $$
and so your functional equation is
$$ f(x,y) = \frac{1}{1-y} + \frac12 B_+(2,3,f;x,y) + \frac12 B_-(2,3,f;x,y).$$
The quantities $B_\pm$ satisfy the expression

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} B_\pm(m,n,h;x,y) = m B_\pm(m-1,n,h;x,y) + B_\pm(m,n+1,\partial_x h;x,y) $$

Denote by $f^{(k)} = \partial^k_x f$. We find

$$ f^{(1)}(x,y) = B_+(1,3,f;x,y) + \frac12 B_+(2,4,f^{(1)};x,y) + \text{minus terms}$$

$$ f^{(2)}(x,y) = B_+(0,3,f;x,y) + 2B_+(1,4,f^{(1)};x,y) + \frac12 B_+(2,5,f^{(2)};x,y) + \ldots$$

Observe that if $m > 0$, the $B_\pm(m,n,h;0,y) = 0$.

So by induction, there exists coefficients $c_{kj}$

$$ f^{(k)}(0,y) = \sum_{j = 0}^{k-2} c_{kj} B_+(0,k+1+j,f^{(j)};0,y) + \text{minus terms} \tag{A}$$

Note furthermore that

$$ B_\pm(0,n,h;0,y) = \frac{1}{(1\pm \sqrt{y})^n} \frac{h(0,y) - h(0,0)}{y} $$

So starting from $f(0,y) = \frac{1}{1-y}$, we actually find that for every $k \geq 0$,
$$ f^{(k)}(0,y) = \frac{P_k(y)}{(1-y)^M} \tag{B}$$
where $M = M(k)$ is some natural number and $P_k$ is some polynomial of $y$.

---

What is the up shot? Well, if one were clever and spends a lot of time on this, one can in principle write down the coefficients $c_{kj}$ in (A) (which I think should be all integers). Solving this recursion relation will give you the explicit formulae for $P_k$ and $M(k)$ in (B). This has the following consequences,

> If there is a real analytic solution $f$ to your system, then this $f$ is unique, and you can compute its values in a neighborhood of $\{0\}\times [0,\infty)$ by its Taylor expansions.

Comment: Thank you, I constructed this function as generating function to a certain sequence $(d(n,m))$, so I am assuming the function to be analytic around zero any way. I only found a recurrence for $d(n,m)$ in both parameters simultaneously, but your answer should help me get to a direct recurrence without the second parameter.